# jQuery - Make hight value is the same width value

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I try to make the width an height the same value.

My code

```
var getWidth = ($(".square").width());
$('.square').css('height',getWidth +'px');
```

But when I resize window it don't work.

I need way to work with it with jquery or sass.

Thinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getsquare(){
var getWidth = $(".square").width();
$('.square').css('height',getWidth +'px');
}
getsquare();
$(window).resize(function(){
getsquare()
});
```

The above code works perfectly in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqkbk20y/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an event handler for when the page resizes if you want the square to update.

jQuery: [`.on('resize', handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.resize(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yt9oa20y/)

JS

```
function squareSize (e) {
  var sq = $('.square');
      sq.css('height', sq.width());        
}

squareSize();

$(window).on('resize', squareSize);
```

jQuery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var getWidth = $(".square").width();
$('.square').css('height',getWidth);

$( window ).resize(function() {
 var getWidth = $(".square").width();
$('.square').css('height',getWidth);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This script don't make width equal to height forever , its just taking width value and assigning to height. You need to again take width from object and assign to height on resize event.

Best way to wrap it in function and call that function at current flow and on resize event.

```
function assignWidthtoHeight(){
var getWidth = ($(".square").width());
$('.square').css('height',getWidth +'px');
 }

assignWidthtoHeight();

$( window ).resize(function() {
assignWidthtoHeight();
});
```

Comment: @MostafaNawara If these solutions worked for you. Kindly accept one of the answer so that other people also know that it worked for you. You and answerer will also get some reputation. You can accept the one of answer using checkbox and upvote as many as answers you like by clicking top arrow.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this rearranged code, a little bit you have to change on your code. we need to write .css() function with second bracket.

```
var getWidth = $(".square").width();
$('.square').css({height: getWidth+'px'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xf7kjcf6/19/

Comment: if you like the answer then you can support us by giving a thumbsup, and  we will get more inspiration for for answering question :)